# How to create a "Last 25 Threads you've participated in" page with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, forum

I am creating a "Previous 25 Threads You've Participated In" page on my web site for my forum, but I can't quite figure out the SQL to do it. It needs to go into the "replies" table, find the most recent 25 that the user has participated in ('poster' column), but they cannot have the same 'topic' column. Then, it needs to order it by the 'last_post' int inside of the 'topic' table. The 'topic' column in the 'replies' table corresponds to the 'id' column in the 'topics' table.

Any help?

Table Structure:

```
--f_topics--
id (int)
subject (varchar)
poster (varchar)
category (int)
posted (varchar)
type (varchar)
last_post (int)
views (int)
locked (int)

--f_replies--
id (int)
poster (varchar)
content (text)
date (varchar)
topic (int)
subject (varchar)
last_post (int)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It would be easier to help you if you were a little more explicit about your table structures, as well as any queries you have already tried, and where you are having the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to begin to write a query that could do this, so I have not tried anything. I have however researched around and I have found nothing useful.

Comment: Ok your question is confusing - try giving the table structure with sample data, what the expected result should be, and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id, t.subject, t.poster, t.category,
       t.posted, t.last_post, t.views, t.locked
FROM f_topics t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM f_replies r
    WHERE r.topic = t.id
    AND r.poster = :user -- this is a query parameter, use PDO
)
ORDER BY t.last_post DESC
LIMIT 25
```

In case you're not familiar with query parameters or PDO, please see:

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- [PDO::prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- [PDOStatement::bindParam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
- [PDOStatement::execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
- [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: was gonna post a vague reply similar to this, but this is much better

Comment: last_post is the Unix Time of when the last reply was posted to the topic, and last_post in the replies table is when the reply was posted

Comment: @user1059057 You know MySQL has [date/time data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), right?